# .wpp.targets is published to server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

Here's my build&publish command:

```
MSBuild.exe D:\github\myProj\myProj\myProj.vbproj /p:PublishProfile=myProj.pubxml /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

Here's my file structure:

[image: file structure]

Why is my myProj.wpp.targets ignored, and even published to server?

If it contained errors, it shouldn't at least be published.

My project is asp.net 3.5 visual basic. I am really stuck. First/best tip that leads to solution will be rewarded.

Comment: Where is your myProj.pubxml file?

Comment: It's in <project root>\My Project\PublishProfiles. There's nothing wrong with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following at the end of your build&command MSBuild.exe command:

```
/p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile=<path-to.targets-file>
```

which will be in your case:

```
/p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile=D:\github\myProj\myProj\myProj.wpp.targets
```

I hope, this will work!

Comment: @John Mcfiddly was helpful the answer?

Comment: It has no effect so there must be error in my .targets file. I will mark it as correct when bounty ends if nothing else comes up.

Comment: @JohnMcFiddly, try to check your .targets file. The solution that I have uploaded detects the .wpp.targets file

Comment: Yes, it detects my .targets file. You answered my question well. (But still it don't work so there's an error in my code)