# .wpp.targets file is ignored during build

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, webdeploy

I'm trying to apply custom ACLs using webdeploy (set `Write` permission to a folder - the folder is empty but added to the project and correctly deployed).

I'm building a VS solution on my CI server with the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
            /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly
            /maxcpucount
            /nologo
            /property:Configuration=Release
            /p:Platform=x86
            /verbosity:quiet
            MySolution.sln
            /p:DeployOnBuild=True
            /p:PublishProfile="ci"
            /p:ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled=False
            /p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile="MyProject\MyProject.wpp.targets"
```

It builds correctly but it completely ignores the content of my `MyProject.wpp.targets`. I tried to write wrong XML but it gets silently ignored, the build is successful but clearly without my `wpp.targets` applied. The `/p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile` parameter doesn't have any effect.

This is the content of `MyProject.wpp.targets`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">   
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
        <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\Content\cache</Path>
        <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
        <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
        <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="ContentCacheSetAclParam">
        <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
        <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
        <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\Content\\cache$</Match>
        <Description>Add write permission to the Content/cache folder.</Description>
        <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/Content/cache</DefaultValue>
        <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/Content/cache</Value>
        <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
        <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
        <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The project is a `net641` csproj `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`.

What's wrong with my configuration? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Obvious question, but does `MyProject\MyProject.wpp.targets` exist relative to the directory that your .sln file is in?
Also curious why you're using `WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile` instead of relying on the default behaviour for a project named `MyProject.csproj` to load `MyProject.wpp.targets`?

Comment: @DavidGardiner yes, the `MyProject\MyProject.wpp.targets` file is there beside the `MyProject\MyProject.csproj` file, the `.sln` is one level up, I triple-checked. Regarding the `WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile` switch I tried at first without, after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316389/wpp-targets-is-published-to-server) I added it but it makes no differences, the build succeeds but the file is completely ignored.